# I want to get product attirbute in the section below

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to add product brand and weight which i have defined in attribute of product but it am using the

```
<?php
$weightvalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_weight');

      foreach ( $weightvalues as $weightvalue ) {
       echo $weightvalue->name;
        } ?>
```

which i have used in the product page but its not working inthe code below.
What should i do?

```
<?php 
$title='';
                        if($show_title)
                        {
                            //$title = '<h3 class="ls-result-title"><a href="'.$product->get_permalink().'">'.$product->get_title().'</a></h3>';
                            $variation_label='';
                            if(get_post_type($pid)=='product_variation'){
                                $all_meta = get_post_meta( $pid );
                                foreach ( $all_meta as $name => $value ) {
                                    if ( ! strstr( $name, 'attribute_' ) ) {
                                         continue;
                                    }
                                    if($value[0]!='')
                                        $variation_label.=' - '.str_replace(array("pa_","attribute_"),"",$name).' : '.$value[0];
                                }

                            }


                            $title = '<h3 class="ls-result-title"><span class="brand"></span><a href="'.$product->get_permalink().'">'.$product->get_title().$variation_label .$terms.' </a></h3><h4></h4>';
                        }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the Answer by fiddling around a bit

```
<?php echo $_product->get_attribute( 'pa_weight' );?>
```